# control characters (\n, \t, etc) are not being updated in the textarea input immediately

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea

My first issue is, in the textarea if I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> when its empty and start typing, the value it contains does not have the `\t` character in the beginning of the string. (Irrespective of how many times the tab key was pressed prior to typing normal text).

Second issue. After typing is some text and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>, again the `\t` character doesn't appear in the value. However, if I resume typing text at this moment, value in the textarea now contains that `\t` character as expected at that position. This is the case if I typed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `\n` character doesn't appear; but if I kept on typing it appears in the same fashion as before?

How to handle these two issues?

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = {
      txt: ''
    };

    $scope.kd = function(e) {

      if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        var ta = angular.element(e.target);
        var val = ta.val();
        var st = ta[0].selectionStart,
          ed = ta[0].selectionEnd;
        ta.val(val.substring(0, st) + '\t' + val.substring(ed));
        ta[0].selectionStart = ta[0].selectionEnd = st + 1;
        //console.log(ta.triggerHandler);
        ta.triggerHandler('change');
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <textarea ng-model="foo.txt" rows="10" cols="75" ng-keydown="kd($event)"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <pre>
      {{ foo | json }}
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular automatically trims the input value. Set `ng-trim="false"` on input tag to disable default trimming.

**[ngTrim](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)**

> If set to false Angular will not automatically trim the input. This
>   parameter is ignored for input[type=password] controls, which will
>   never trim the input.
>
> (default: true)

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = {
      txt: ''
    };

    $scope.kd = function(e) {

      if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        var ta = angular.element(e.target);
        var val = ta.val();
        var st = ta[0].selectionStart,
          ed = ta[0].selectionEnd;
        ta.val(val.substring(0, st) + '\t' + val.substring(ed));
        ta[0].selectionStart = ta[0].selectionEnd = st + 1;
        //console.log(ta.triggerHandler);
        ta.triggerHandler('change');
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <textarea ng-model="foo.txt" rows="10" cols="75" ng-trim="false" ng-keydown="kd($event)"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <pre>
      {{ foo | json }}
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```